# IPv6 connection between 2 computers doesn't work

Tags: linux, ipv6

I have 2 Linux computers with the following IPv6 addresses:

```
1: fe80::de0e:a1ff:fe15:13e0  prefixlen 64
2: fe80::2e0:4cff:feb0:f8d  prefixlen 64
```

When on the first computer I try:

```
# ping fe80::2e0:4cff:feb0:f8d
ping: unknown host fe80::2e0:4cff:feb0:f8d
```

So, it seems, that the addresses are assigned incorrectly, and it can't find the 2-nd computer. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use `ping6`.  Secondly, you need to specify an interface with `-I`; as the `man` page says:

> -I interface
>
> [...] For ping6, when doing ping to a link-local scope address, link specification
>   (by the '%'-notation in destination, or by this option) is required.

*Et voila*:

```
[me@risby scratch]$ ping6 -I p1p1 fe80::213:72ff:feba:3750
[...]
64 bytes from fe80::213:72ff:feba:3750: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.232 ms
64 bytes from fe80::213:72ff:feba:3750: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.786 ms
```